# How can i know whether Rabbitmq acked success?

Tags: rabbitmq

When I set up manual Ack with RMQ, but how could i know whether ack is successfully done?If there is a exception before basic.ack when i have long operations to perform, the message will be sent to another consumer .How can i avoid that?

Comment: What is your specific problem? What language, platform do you use? Can you show some code to demonstrate problem you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i avoid that?

You can't.

At some point it will happen and your code needs to deal with this scenario gracefully. This is typically done with [idempotence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) in your message processing.

That is, you allow the message to be processed more than once (because it will happen), but you only make the underlying change to the system once.

A common / simple way of handling this is to have an ID associated with each message. Before processing the message, check to see if that ID is marked as complete in your database. If it's not, then process the message. When the message is processed, you update a database with that ID. That way, when (not if) you run into the scenario where a message is processed twice, you won't actually do the processing / system changes twice.